# make jack audio from gpio beaglebone

Tags: audio, beagleboneblack

I need to play a mp3 file in beaglebone black rev C. Unlike raspberry, BBB does not have jack audio. I have  USB audio adapter, but I want to build a new jack audio using GPIO pin in BBB.

I installed arch linux in my BBB and use mplayer to play mp3 file.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PWM pin to modulation audio signal! Begin you need decoder mp3 to pcm code.![enter image description here][1]